# capture Camera view with Google Earth API

Tags: javascript, screenshot, google-earth-plugin

Is it possible to programmatically capture the camera view from the Google Earth API?

Comment: No, not in the browser - your best bet would be the `Print Screen` button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *copyAsLookAt()* function to return the latitude and longitude where the camera is looking, etc. In example below, the returned values are passed to a new *lookAt* object:

```
var lookAt = ge.getView().copyAsLookAt(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
```

Similarly, the view can be returned as a Camera value:

```
var camera = ge.getView().copyAsCamera(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
```

The rule of thumb is that if the view direction intersects the planet then a *LookAt* orientation is all that you need. If view direction is above the horizon then you need a Camera view.

Source: https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/camera_control#current_view

Comment: Thanks, however I'm actually trying to capture a rasterized image of the camera contents. Pipe it to a folder maybe? I don't see anything in the documentation indicating this is possible with the stock functionality in the API.

Comment: For security reasons there is no access between javascript and the local file system. This is not a limitation on the Google Earth Plug-in, it is how the javascript sandbox works. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Security

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "ScreenGrab" function?

```
bmp = geWebBrowser1.ScreenGrab();
```

Comment: This is a function for the GEWebBrowser contol in this library - http://code.google.com/p/winforms-geplugin-control-library/ it isn't really part of the Google Earth Api.